# Линия между двумя точками с координатами в Gmap.NET на c#

Tags: c#, gmap.net

Я использую библиотеку для работы с картами *GMap.NET*. У меняя есть 3 точки с координатами, как мне нарисовать линию между ними?

P.S. Мне нужна **просто линия** между точками, а не маршрут (по дорогам и т.д.)

Comment: Хорошо) У меня есть несколько точек. Я знаю их координаты.Дальше мне необходимо построить линию между этими точками. Именно линию, а не маршрут (то есть НЕ по дорогам, а просто линию)

Comment: Спасибо большое)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поискал и нашел довольно хороший пример.

```
GMapOverlay routes = new GMapOverlay("routes"); //Создаем объект наложения (Overlay)
List<PointLatLng> points = new List<PointLatLng>(); //Создаем лист, где будут наши точки пути.
points.Add(new PointLatLng(48.866383, 2.323575)); //Добавляем координаты
points.Add(new PointLatLng(48.863868, 2.321554));
points.Add(new PointLatLng(48.861017, 2.330030));
GMapRoute route = new GMapRoute(points, "A walk in the park"); //Создаем из полученных точнек маршрут и даем ей имя.
route.Stroke = new Pen(Color.Red, 3); //Задаем цвет и ширину линии
routes.Routes.Add(route); //Добавляем на наш Overlay маршрут
gmap1.Overlays.Add(routes); //Накладываем Overlay на карту.

GMapOverlay markersOverlay = new GMapOverlay("marker"); //Создаем Overlay
GMarkerGoogle markerStart = new GMarkerGoogle(points.FirstOrDefault(), GMarkerGoogleType.blue); //Создаем новую точку и даем ей координаты первого элемента из листа координат и синий цвет
GMarkerGoogle markerEnd = new GMarkerGoogle(points.LastOrDefault(), GMarkerGoogleType.red); //Тоже самое, но красный цвет и последний из списка координат.
markerStart.ToolTip = new GMapRoundedToolTip(markerStart); //Указываем тип всплывающей подсказки для точки старта
markerEnd.ToolTip = new GMapBaloonToolTip(markerEnd); //Другой тип подсказки для точки окончания (для теста)
markerStart.ToolTipText = "Точка старта"; //Текст всплывающих подсказок при наведении
markerEnd.ToolTipText = "Точка окончания";

markersOverlay.Markers.Add(markerStart); //Добавляем точки
markersOverlay.Markers.Add(markerEnd); //В наш оверлей маркеров

gmap1.Overlays.Add(markersOverlay); //Добавляем оверлей на карту
```

Также я применял настройки для самого элемента, где указал что используется карта Google, перетаскивание левой клавишей мыши, цент при приближении у курсора, а также мин и макс зум карты.

```
public void Setting()
    {
        gmap1.Bearing = 0;
        gmap1.CanDragMap = true;
        gmap1.DragButton = MouseButtons.Left;
        gmap1.GrayScaleMode = true;

        gmap1.MarkersEnabled = true;
        gmap1.MaxZoom = 18;
        gmap1.MinZoom = 2;

        gmap1.MouseWheelZoomType = GMap.NET.MouseWheelZoomType.MousePositionAndCenter;
        gmap1.NegativeMode = false;
        gmap1.PolygonsEnabled = true;
        gmap1.RoutesEnabled = true;
        gmap1.ShowTileGridLines = false;
        gmap1.Zoom = 5;
        gmap1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

        gmap1.MapProvider = GMap.NET.MapProviders.GoogleMapProvider.Instance;
        GMap.NET.GMaps.Instance.Mode = GMap.NET.AccessMode.ServerOnly;
    }
```

[image: Результат]

[Источник](http://www.independent-software.com/gmap-net-beginners-tutorialadding-polygons-and-routes-to-your-map-updated-for-visual-studio-2015-and-gmap-net-1-7/)

---

То, что вам надо - называется `polyline`. Делается это при помощи создания полигона выделения.

Пример следующий:

```
GMapOverlay polyOverlay = new GMapOverlay("polygons"); //Оверлей
List<PointLatLng> points = new List<PointLatLng>(); //Лист с точками
points.Add(new PointLatLng(48.866383, 2.323575));
points.Add(new PointLatLng(48.861017, 2.330030));
GMapPolygon polygon = new GMapPolygon(points, "mypolygon"); //Создаем полигон
polygon.Fill = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(50, Color.Red));
polygon.Stroke = new Pen(Color.Red, 1);
polyOverlay.Polygons.Add(polygon);
gmap1.Overlays.Add(polyOverlay);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пока, к сожалению, не заработало, но я продолжу разбираться)

Comment: @Alexander Что именно не заработало? Может просто не нашли ее на карте? (я лично пол часа сидел и искал этот маршрут).

Comment: @Alexander Поправил ответ, теперь у линии будут сначала и конца маркеры, ну а также свои настройки для элемента добавил, может поможет.

Comment: Спасибо огромное за подробный пример. Дело в том, что мне не нужем маршрут (по дорогам и т.д.). Мне нужна просто линия между точками)

Comment: @Alexander Добавил в ответ то, что вам вроде нужно.

Comment: Спасибо огромное!))))