# C# POST запрос для доступа к API

Tags: c#, http, post, request

Необходимо выполнить POST запрос на один сайт, у меня есть ключ к его API. Можете, пожалуйста, подсказать, как можно реализовать запрос к сайту с помощью c#. Вот пример (который там называется "Примерный" запрос):

```
curl -u {API_KEY}: -i -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"Param1":"Value1","Param2":"Value2"}' https:/название сайта.
```

Спасибо заранее за помощь)

Comment: полностью можете опубликовать? Или отправить ссылку на документацию?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Попробуйте следующее:

```
var key = "1111";    
var request = WebRequest.Create("URL");
request.ContentType = "application/json";
request.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + key;

request.Method = "POST";

using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
{
    string json = "{\"param1\":\"val\",\"param2\":\"val\"}";
    streamWriter.Write(json);
}


HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
{
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.UTF8);
    Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd());
}
```

Comment: Сейчас попробую)

Comment: Спасибо огромное) Работает)

Comment: Если Вам не сложно, могли бы Вы подсказать по этому вопросу? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/706823/%D0%9B%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%BC%D1%8F-%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D1%81-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%B2-gmap-net-%D0%BD%D0%B0-c

Comment: @Alexander Данная тема для меня совсем не знакома, попробую посмотреть примеры, может пойму что. Если разберусь, дам ответ.

Comment: Спасибо) Я тоже сейчас сижу, разбираюсь)