# Отправить POST запрос с JSON телом C#

Tags: c#, json, qiwi

Как отправить запрос я разобрался (использую библиотеку xNet), а как изменить  его тело нет, дайте пример с использованием xNet или стандартных методов. Ниже пример запроса, это QIWI API, если что. Спасибо.

[image: Пример запроса]

Вот код, который отправляет запрос:

```
private void button21_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  using (var request = new HttpRequest())
  {
    var urlParams = new RequestParams();

    request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    request.AddHeader("Content-Type:", "application/json");
    request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + textBox56.Text);

    string content = request.Post("https://edge.qiwi.com/sinap/api/v2/terms/99/payments", urlParams).ToString();
    textBox58.Text = content;
  }
}
```

Comment: Прикрепил код, который отправляет заголовки, то что уже сделал сам

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/706894/220553

Answer (score 1):

Пример не с библиотекой xNet , может быть поможет

```
  var stringContent = new StringContent("putJsonThere", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
  var response = await new HttpClient().PostAsync(url?param1=1&param2=2, stringContent);
```

Answer (score 1):

с `xnet` будет примерно так

```
request.Useragent = "";
request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + textBox56.Text);
string json = "{\"id\":\"11111111\",\"sum\":{\"amount\":10.50, \"currency\":\"643\"},.........}";
string content = request.Post("https://edge.qiwi.com/sinap/api/v2/terms/99/payments", json,"application/json").ToString();
```

т.к картинка, а не код, то мне было лень все переписывать, но ты понял суть, все в одну строку записывай без переходов, а перед кавычкой ставь слэш `\`

Answer (score 0):

Можно как то так:

```
var serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
var json = serializer.Serialize(new { id = 123, sum = new { amount = 0, currency = 643 } });
var response = request.Post(address, json, contentType)
```

Сериализовать можно что захотите