# Проблема с доступом к qiwi api с помощью библиотеки xNet c#

Tags: c#, api, qiwi, xnet

В другом вопросе нашел, что можно работать с qiwi api с помощью библиотеки xNet. Но появилась проблема вылезает данная ошибка [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сам код:`using (var request = new HttpRequest())
            {
                request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + "128e26ea61eaf474fc6eb33a00b6ffef");
                string json = "{\"id\":\"11111111119\",\"sum\":{\"amount\":1, \"currency\":\"643\"},\"paymentMethod\":{\"type\":\"Account\", \"accountId\":\"643\"},\"comment\":\"test\",\"fields\":{\"account\":\"+79201214835\"}}";
                Console.WriteLine(json);
                string content = request.Post("https://edge.qiwi.com/sinap/api/v2/terms/99/payments", json, "application/json").ToString();
            }`

Ссылка на киви апи https://developer.qiwi.com/ru/qiwi-wallet-personal/index.html?http#p2p

Ссылка на xNet библиотеку https://www.dllme.com/getfile.php?file=26811&id=ac1dceddbc66a1ab7915ac9931f0cfec

Ссылка на вопрос на стаке где нашел данное решение [Отправить POST запрос с JSON телом C#](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/710554/%d0%9e%d1%82%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-post-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81-%d1%81-json-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%bc-c/710613#710613)

Вот что должно отправляться на сервер qiwi [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Во первых, у XNet есть официальный репозиторий. Во вторых, XNet давно устарел и не продвигается автором, также он написан на .net 4 версии, что делает данную библиотеку несовместимой с новыми протоколами (tls выше 1 версии). Ну и в третьих, вам сервер дает код ошибки и сообщение, которое какраз XNet глушит и не выдает вам стандартными путями. Я советую вам получить это сообщение и смотреть что конкретно не нравиться серверу, ибо судя по документации у вас `Ошибка синтаксиса запроса (неправильный формат данных)`.

Comment: А как можно без xnet?

Comment: Просто довольно много через чего пробовал ничего не получалось

Comment: Так же хотел узнать а где этот их репозиторий?

Comment: В C# - `HttpClient`, все остальные являются устаревшими. Я как-то [писал](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/828951/220553) ответ для киви, как раз с этим классом. Репозиторий [XNet](https://github.com/X-rus/xNet), заметьте, 4 года...

Comment: Да, я видел только у меня почему-то это не заработало. Мне показалось это очень странным.

Comment: Если я с утра по мск скину код, не подскажите в чем ошибка?) Ваш код который вы писали.

Comment: В чем ошибка - должны сказать нам Вы, ибо только Вам известно это. Пишите как дополнение к вопросу (кнопка "править" под ним) и меня через `@` не забудьте оповестить в комментариях, гляну тогда что натворили. Только пожалуйста, подробней, что бы у нас с вам не возник диалог на несколько дней, где я вытягиваю из вас все детали.