# paypal api (sandbox) как с ним работать

Tags: c#, paypal, paypal-api

у меня консольное приложение которая 
1) должна создавать аккаунты в sandbox
2) можно передавать между аккаунтами деньги 
узаю paypal sdk .net

app.config

```
<settings>
      <add name="mode" value="sandbox" />
      <add name="clientId" value="my id" />
      <add name="clientSecret" value="my secret" />
</settings>
```

code

```
    var config = ConfigManager.Instance.GetProperties();

    var accessToken = new OAuthTokenCredential(config).GetAccessToken();

    var apiContext = new APIContext(accessToken);
```

как дальше не могу понять

Comment: Уважаемый, это простейший API, как и у 90% всего интернета. Отправляете запрос на один адрес, тот дает вам токен доступа, далее на все другие адреса вы отправляете post/get/delete и др. запросы с заголовком `Authorization: Bearer [токен]`. Если вы не понимаете подробно расписанную [официальную](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/overview/#authentication-and-authorization) документацию, так может не строит вам за это браться и подучить основы? P.S. Есть [SDK](http://paypal.github.io/PayPal-NET-SDK/) для работы с API PayPal с тоже весьма хорошей документацией.

Comment: Спасибо вот этого я не мог найти

Comment: можете простой пример показать

Comment: другие api и документация довольно понятно, с paypal api не могу разобраться

Comment: Простой пример - хм, [вот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/828951/220553). Конкретно с PayPal - нет. ибо нужна регистрация и создания ключа доступа (что сейчас я сделать не смогу), но принцип там тот же. Идем [сюда](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/overview/#make-your-first-call)  и по пунктам все расписано. 1. Создаем приложение. 2. На `/v1/oauth2/token` отправляем `POST` запрос с телом формата `application/json` или `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, в теле должен быть `client_id`. В ответ сервер даст нам `access_token`, который в последующем отправляем в заголовке при каждом запросе.