# Отправить POST запрос с JSON телом при помощи WebClient (C#)

Tags: c#, .net, json, http, webclient

Если я правильно понимаю, то `WebClient` высокоуровневый, даже выше чем `HttpClient`.

Я пытаюсь с помощью него отправить `POST-запрос`, который в теле содержит данные в `формате JSON`. В ответ должен придти **бинарный файл**, который необходимо сохранить на файловую систему:

```
using (var webClient = new WebClient())
{
    webClient.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json");
    var uri = new Uri("http://...");
    var values = new NameValueCollection
    {
        { "property1Name", "property1Value" },
        { "property2Name", "property2Value" },
    };

    var responseBytes = webClient.UploadValues(uri, values);
}
```

Но при выполнение данного кода выскакивает `WebException: Content-Type cannot be changed for current petition`.

Comment: [POSTing JSON to URL via WebClient in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15091300/posting-json-to-url-via-webclient-in-c-sharp)?

Comment: `UploadValues` и `NameValueCollection` это `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. Для отправки именно `application/json` надо использовать `StringContent` и метод `Post`. К примеру [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/828951/220553) можно глянуть пример отправки.