# Почему не передается параметр через HTTP Post

Tags: c#, xamarin

Только начал изучать технологию делаю по примеру:
Kласс который хочу передать.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
namespace learning_27_11
{
[Serializable]
public class Authorization
 {
   public string Login { get; set; }
   public string Password { get; set; }
 }
}
```

Код мобильного клиента:

```
string login_ = Convert.ToString(loginEntry.Text);
string pass_ = Convert.ToString(passwordEntry.Text);
Authorization authorization = new learning_27_11.Authorization()
    {
       Login = login_,
       Password = pass_
    };       
string jsonStr = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(authorization);
Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>()
{
  {"key",jsonStr}
};
FormUrlEncodedContent form = new FormUrlEncodedContent(dict);
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(Url, form);
string result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
await DisplayAlert("результат", result,"OK");
```

Код сервера:

```
public string Post([FromBody]string key)
        {
            Models.Authorization authorization = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Models.Authorization>(key);
            Avtoriz avtoriz = new Avtoriz(authorization.Login,authorization.Password);
            if (avtoriz.correct) { return "Работает c correct"; }
            return "Работает";
        }
```

На сервер данные не приходят, т.е. key остается null

Попробовал по описанному примеру:

```
 var body = new Authorization
            {
                Login = login_,
                Password = pass_
            };
```

Далее метод для отправки:

```
public async Task<string> SendRequest(string url, object body)
        {
            string data;

            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
               var content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(body), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                var result = await client.PostAsync(url, content);
                data = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            }
```

И как ты говорил на сервере:

```
public string Post([FromBody]Models.Authorization key)
{
//Models.Authorization authorization = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Models.Authorization>(key);
Avtoriz avtoriz = new Avtoriz(key.Login,key.Password);
if (avtoriz.correct) { return "Работает c correct"; }
return "Работает";
}
```

Comment: `FormUrlEncodedContent` - это если я не ошибаюсь `x-www-form-urlencoded`. `[FromBody]` - тут если я не ошибаюсь `application/json`. Для приема данных в формате формы измените `[FromBody]` на `[FromForm]`. Либо переделывайте отправку запроса на грамотную отправку типа `application/json`.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Попробовал поменять на [FromForm] нет такого аргумента из возможных есть только [FromUri] ну ли соответственно[FromBody],  но как я понял это не то.  если не сложно можно чуть более подробнее о "грамотную отправку типа application/json" в какую сторону копать

Comment: Чем у вас является сервер? Пример отправки JSON можете например глянуть в этом [ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/828951/220553). Только учтите, что `[FromBody]string key` - это ожидание объекта вида string, если вы используете Asp.net, то указывать нужно уже десериализируемый тип (то есть `Models.Authorization`), ручная десериализация лишняя.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Сервер приложение WebApi

Comment: @EvgeniyZ А подскажи пожалуйста! сделал по примеру, но не получается, что я не правильно понял?

Comment: В `public string Post` заходит хотя бы? И какие у него атрибуты?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Да в public string Post заходит. [FromBody]Models.Authorization key класс Authorization using System;
namespace server.Models
{
    [Serializable]
    public class Authorization
    {
        public string Login { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
    }

Comment: Мне не удалось воспроизвести вашу проблему. Прям скопировал от сюда ваш класс, ваш метод, метод приема, сделал на пустом проекте Asp.net Core контроллер с вашим Post методом и классом данных, поставил брекпоинт и отправил через другой проект запрос - все успешно [передалось](https://evgeniy-z.ru/data.gif).

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Большое спасибо!  Буду искать проблему в другом