# Как задать curl запрос в С#

Tags: c#, api, post, curl

Пример curl-запроса:

-X POST -H 'Content-type: application/json' -d '{"items":[{"views":0,"entity":{"_id":"15875","type":"events"},"updateDate":1449486061000,"url":"http://www.culture.ru/materials/56296","likes":0,"statuses":["featured","published"]}]}' https://all.culture.ru/api/2.2/import?apiKey=apiKey

Как его задать на С#?

Comment: Curl на окнах ты сможешь запускать из cygwin. Дальше вопрос сводится как комманду cygwin запустить из cmd. Ну а как cmd дёрнуть из Java for Windows можешь почитать здесь: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1469764/run-command-prompt-commands. То есть curl->cygwin->cmd->c#

Comment: Явного курла вроде нету, но возможно на nuget что-то уже есть. В с# есть класс, через который всё описанное можно сделать [httpwebrequest](http://docs.microsoft.com/ru-Ru/dotnet/api/system.net.httpwebrequest)

Comment: с# язык более низкого уровня чем php, он предполагает передачу байт, а не запроса, но используя  httpwebrequest + Encoding.GetBytes можно сделать функцию похожую на curl. Похожие вопросы http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7929013/making-a-curl-call-in-c-sharp

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [C# POST запрос для доступа к API](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/706871/c-post-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%b4%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%83%d0%bf%d0%b0-%d0%ba-api)